# Get a boolean value if an edge exsists in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I want to do a simple query in which I have a user and a group.  Users have an edge "memberOf" to group vertex. Given a userId and a groupId, I want to write a query that returns true or false if there is an edge between the user and the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding a second answer to mention that you can also use the `hasNext` step for this. It will return true or false depending on whether the target exists.

```java
g.V().hasId('userid').
      out().hasId('group1').
      hasNext()
```

Comment: this is spot on

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` to do such operation.

```
g.V().hasId('userid').coalesce(out().hasId('group1').constant(true), constant(false))
```